# Moving Objects By Android Touch

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

by my code down here i am trying to grab the objects and move them around . but after little finger move on android device my object will be gone.
my code:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved){
            if(hitObject !=null && hitObject.tag=="G"){
                hitObject.transform.Translate(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x,Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y,1f);
        }
        }
```

its a 2D game . what is my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objects have a `Rigidbody`, use the `MovePosition` method of that component. Should cause less problems and be more accurate.

```
Vector3 touch = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
rigidbody.MovePosition(touch);
```